# What fractional equation does this convolution solve

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, fractional-calculus

Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is an infinitely differentiable with compact support and let $E_{\alpha}$ be the one-parameter Mittag-Leffler function with $0<\alpha<1$. Find the fractional differential or integral equation the following integral satisfies:

$$u(t,x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}E_{\alpha}(-t^{\alpha}(x-y)^2)f(y)dy.\quad (1)$$

It is well-know that

$E_{\alpha}(-t^{\alpha} x^2)f(x)$ solves the fractional differential equation

$$D^{\alpha}_{t} u(t,x)+x^2 u(t,x)=0,\quad (t,x)\in (0,\infty)\times \mathbb{R},$$
with the initial condition $u(0,x)=f(x)$.

Here $D^{\alpha}_{t}$ denotes the Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative of order $\alpha$ defined by

$$ D^{\alpha}_{t}g(t)
=\frac{1}{\Gamma{(1-\alpha)}}
\left(\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{0}^{t}
\frac{g(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha}}ds\right)-
\frac{g(0)}{t^{\alpha}}\right).
$$

What about the convolution $(1)$ ?